# How to handle tree like structure in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat, internet-explorer-10

I am trying to implement a hierarchical structure in the form of a tree in a complex angular.js web app. I am using nested ng-repeats to render the structure but I am getting significant performance related issues in IE 10 and minor performance issues in chrome. Data that will be used will contain as many as 5,000 entries at the final level.
Based on my research I think following could be the reasons behind it:

1. **Large number of watcher elements.** 
   To tackle this I have already implemented one time data binding and number of watchers is not that high.
2. **Browser repaint time:**
   ng-repeat adds the elements to the DOM one by one. This could result in overloading of browser engine to render complex HTML multiple number of times causing large amount of lags.
   To tackle this I have applied lazy loading sort of technique by rendering the child only when one node is collapsed. Still I am experiencing an observable delay in rendering of nodes where the number of nodes to be rendered is large.
3. **CSS classes:**
   I tried implementing the tree structure by stripping off all the classes from node elements. This resulted in significant improvement but removing classes is not really an option. Also if I give inline style to the elements then it also results in better performance.
4. **Performance issues of Angular material:**
   Angular material is the integral part of my web app. After looking into the issues submitted by angular material users for large amount of ng-repeats to which fixes have already been rolled out. But upgrading to latest version didn't help either.

Please [refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4WpY.png) to this image for the table design. Template used for the creation of tree is as follows:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ::item.childLevelDetails" >
 <div >
    <a ng-click="toggle(this)" class="icon icon-stream-add-2">
      <span></span>
    </a>
    <div class="unitTextDiv">{{::item.title}}</div>
 </div>
 <ol ng-include= "'tree_node'">
</li>
```

Request you to suggest any possible solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular-ui-grid can be considered as one option. It uses virtualization and renders only the rows that are visible. So, it performs well with huge number of rows too. It comes with a great documentation and examples http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial

Refer to the grouping example to make sure that this helps for your use case http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping

Comment: This looks like a good solution and it is indeed a very handy module... Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this recursive sample I did for you.
Using ng-if for showing/hidding element will reduce the amount of watches.

Here find the [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltmdhsgj/1/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', 'getWatchCount' , function ($scope ,$timeout, getWatchCount ){

 $scope.tree = [
 {title:'Element level 1',
     elements: [
      { title: 'Element level 1.1'},
        { title: 'Element level 1.2',
          elements: [
   { title: 'Element level 1.2.2'},
   { title: 'Element level 1.2.2'},
          ]}
    ]},
     {title:'Element level 2'}
  ]
 
 
 //NEXT CODE ONLY USED FOR COUNTING WATCHES//
 $scope.countWatches = function(){
  $scope.numberOfWatches = getWatchCount();
 }
 
 $timeout(function(){$scope.countWatches()} , 0 );
 
     
 // I return the count of watchers on the current page.
function getWatchCount() {

    // Keep track of the total number of watch bindings on the page.
    var total = 0;

    // There are cases in which two different ng-scope markers will actually be referencing
    // the same scope, such as with transclusion into an existing scope (ie, cloning a node
    // and then linking it with an existing scope, not a new one). As such, we need to make
    // sure that we don't double-count scopes.
    var scopeIds = {};

    // AngularJS denotes new scopes in the HTML markup by appending the classes "ng-scope"
    // and "ng-isolate-scope" to appropriate elements. As such, rather than attempting to
    // navigate the hierarchical Scope tree, we can simply query the DOM for the individual
    // scopes. Then, we can pluck the watcher-count from each scope.
    // --
    // NOTE: Ordinarily, it would be a HUGE SIN for an AngularJS service to access the DOM
    // (Document Object Model). But, in this case, we're not really building a true AngularJS
    // service, so we can break the rules a bit.
    angular.forEach(
        document.querySelectorAll( ".ng-scope , .ng-isolate-scope" ),
        countWatchersInNode
    );

    return( total );


    // ---
    // PRIVATE METHODS.
    // ---


    // I count the $watchers in to the scopes (regular and isolate) associated with the given
    // element node, and add the count to the running total.
    function countWatchersInNode( node ) {

        // Get the current, wrapped element.
        var element = angular.element( node );

        // It seems that in earlier versions of AngularJS, the separation between the regular
        // scope and the isolate scope where not as strong. The element was flagged as having
        // an isolate scope (using the ng-isolate-scope class); but, there was no .isolateScope()
        // method before AngularJS 1.2. As such, in earlier versions of AngularJS, we have to
        // fall back to using the .scope() method for both regular and isolate scopes.
        if ( element.hasClass( "ng-isolate-scope" ) && element.isolateScope ) {

            countWatchersInScope( element.isolateScope() );

        }

        // This class denotes a non-isolate scope in later versions of AngularJS; but,
        // possibly an isolate-scope in earlier versions of AngularJS (1.0.8).
        if ( element.hasClass( "ng-scope" ) ) {

            countWatchersInScope( element.scope() );

        }

    }


    // I count the $$watchers in the given scope and add the count to the running total.
    function countWatchersInScope( scope ) {

        // Make sure we're not double-counting this scope.
        if ( scopeIds.hasOwnProperty( scope.$id ) ) {

            return;

        }

        scopeIds[ scope.$id ] = true;

        // The $$watchers value starts out as NULL until the first watcher is bound. As such,
        // the $$watchers collection may not exist yet on this scope.
        if ( scope.$$watchers ) {

            total += scope.$$watchers.length;

        }

    }

}
 
 }]);

myApp.factory(
   "getWatchCount",
   function() {

    // I return the count of watchers on the current page.
    function getWatchCount() {

     var total = 0;

     // AngularJS denotes new scopes in the HTML markup by appending the
     // class "ng-scope" to appropriate elements. As such, rather than 
     // attempting to navigate the hierarchical Scope tree, we can simply
     // query the DOM for the individual scopes. Then, we can pluck the 
     // watcher-count from each scope.
     // --
     // NOTE: Ordinarily, it would be a HUGE SIN for an AngularJS service
     // to access the DOM (Document Object Model). But, in this case,
     // we're not really building a true AngularJS service, so we can 
     // break the rules a bit.
     angular.element( ".ng-scope" ).each(
      function ngScopeIterator() {

       // Get the scope associated with this element node.
       var scope = $( this ).scope();

       // The $$watchers value starts out as NULL. 
       total += scope.$$watchers
        ? scope.$$watchers.length
        : 0
       ;

      }
     );
     
     return( total );

    }

    // For convenience, let's serialize the above method and convert it to 
    // a bookmarklet that can easily be run on ANY AngularJS page. 
    getWatchCount.bookmarklet = ( 
     "javascript:alert('Watchers:'+(" + 
     getWatchCount.toString()
      .replace( /\/\/.*/g, " " )
      .replace( /\s+/g, " " ) +
     ")());void(0);" 
    );

    return( getWatchCount );

   }
  );
```

```css
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

li{
    font-size:13px;
}
.arrow{
     width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border-left: 7px solid #000;
    display: inline-block;
    transition:all 0.3s; 
}

.arrow.expand {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 20% 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.arrow.none {
    border-left: 7px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl" >

    <p>
  <strong>Watch Count:</strong> {{ numberOfWatches }}
    </p>
    
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="elementTree">
        <li>
            <div class="arrow"
                 
                 ng-class="{expand:element.isOpen,none:!element.elements}"
                 ng-click="$apply(element.isOpen = !element.isOpen) ; countWatches()">
            </div>
            {{element.title}}
        </li>
        <div ng-if="element.isOpen">
            <ul
                ng-repeat="element in element.elements"
                ng-include="'elementTree'">
             </ul
        </div>
        
    </script>
    
    <ul ng-repeat="element in tree"
         ng-include="'elementTree'">
    </ul>
    
    
</div>
```

Comment: Number of watches was never really a problem by using one time bind functionality of angular.The main problem was a heavy delay in rendering of elements. Here is the fork of your [Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/93agvdoj/) that i have modified which showcases the rendering problem

Answer (score 0):

Time to use [stick](http://www.williambrownstreet.net/blog/2014/04/faster-angularjs-rendering-angularjs-and-reactjs/) with this [potion](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html) and finalize according to [black magic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-redux)!